How can I pass parameters from the first YAML pipeline to the second pipeline and trigger the second pipeline?
I need to pass the parameters for test suit id and test case id in the first yaml pipeline and and the same should be passed as the arguments in the second yaml pipeline code so when i trigger the first pipeline it should also trigger the second pipeline.
so, in the below two yml files have i done correctly?? pls check and tell me have provided the yml files,
For the firstpipeline i have written this yml >
name: SecondPipeline

trigger: none

# This pipeline will be triggered by another pipeline

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

parameters:
  - name: testSuiteId
    type: string
    default: ''
  - name: testCaseId
    type: string
    default: ''

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "This pipeline was triggered after the first pipeline completed."
      echo "Test Suite ID: ${{ parameters.testSuiteId }}"
      echo "Test Case ID: ${{ parameters.testCaseId }}"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testSuiteId;isOutput=true]${{ parameters.testSuiteId }}"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testCaseId;isOutput=true]${{ parameters.testCaseId }}"

and for the Secondpipeline I have written this yml,
name: FirstPipeline

variables:
- name: one
  value: 4567

trigger:
- main

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline-par-previous   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: First_Pipeline # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
    project: Cloud_Project # Project name where the source pipeline exists
    trigger: true # enable the trigger

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }}
      echo "Test Suite ID: $(TestSuiteId)"
      echo "Test Case ID: $(TestCaseId)"

I am able to get the values for parameters when i trigger the firstpipeline but how to pass the arguments actually i need to do this > I need to pass the parameters for test suit id and test case id in the first yaml pipeline
and and the same should be passed as the arguments in the second yaml pipeline code so when i trigger the first pipeline it should also trigger the second pipeline.

Variable group should be used here. first pipeline automatically create a variable group   and assign the variable group to second pipeline within a script step, and second pipeline consume the variable group variables.

Here in 1st pipeline I am creating variables (rithvar1,rithvar2) and sending them to 2nd pipeline using below api  from Microsoft-Document:
https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projname/_apis/pipelines/pipelineid/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1

I am invoking above api in pipeline 1.
1st pipeline (test1pipe) :
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest' 

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Hello Rithwik, I am setting varaibles"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=rithvar1]007"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=rithvar2]008"
    name: RithSetVariables

  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $rithvar1 = "${env:rithvar1}"
        $rithvar2 = "${env:rithvar2}"
        $rurl = "https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projname/_apis/pipelines/21/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
        $rb = @{
          resources = @{
            repositories = @{
              self = @{
                refName = "refs/heads/main"
              }
            }
          }
          templateParameters = @{
            rithvar1 = $rithvar1
            rithvar2 = $rithvar2
          }
        } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
        $rh = @{
          Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
          "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        }
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $rurl -Method Post -Body $rb -Headers $rh
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
      rithvar1: $(rithvar1)
      rithvar2: $(rithvar2)

Here 21 is the run id of the pipeline 1.
2nd pipeline (  testpip2):
Here I am getting values from pipeline1 and printing them:
trigger: none
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
parameters:
  - name: rithvar1
    type: string
  - name: rithvar2
    type: string
steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Helo Rithwik this pipeline is trggered by 1st one"
      echo "Variable 1: ${{ parameters.rithvar1 }}"
      echo "variable 2: ${{ parameters.rithvar2 }}"

Output:
After triggering 1 st pipeline :

Then 2nd pipeline gets triggered, values are sent to pipeline 2 and it prints them:

Given Queue builds, Administer build permissions, Edit build pipeline, Edit queue build configuration permissions for second pipeline.
